# How to make an action link with a URL for a previous directory?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, url, directory, actionlink

So I have this action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout","LogoutConfirmation","Login")
```

which takes me to a url like: 
 **mysite.com/myaccount/Login/LogoutConfirmation** 
 however the folder isnt located in "myaccount" its just that is my current location on this webpage.  How can I make the action link to take me to:
 **mysite.com/Login/LogoutConfirmation** 
 instead of the folder "myaccount".

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark: `@Html.ActionLink("Logout","logoutConfirmation", "Login", new {Area=""},null)`

Comment: Thanks, I did almost try that, I just forgot to put null at the end haha,  Thanks, that works great :)

Comment: No problem! Also welcome to Stack Overflow! I noticed you have a couple questions with nothing marked as 'Answered'. Take a second to look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work". Basically just 'Check Mark' an answer if it did solve your question.  I'll add my comment as an answer below as well. Have a good one!

Comment: Thanks Jisaak,  I know StackOverflow very well, this is just a new account as I am working at a new company now.  But thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, just use the overloaded method to include an empty `Area`.

`@Html.ActionLink("Logout","logoutConfirmation", "Login", new {Area=""},null)`